# Proxy Apache Load Balancers to a Unix Socket instead of a port

Tags: ruby-on-rails, apache, sockets, unix, unicorn

How can we do the below Nginx configuration in Apache?
Basically proxying to a Unix socket instead of a load balanced port.
I want that Unicorn handle the load balancing instead of Apache.

```
upstream unicorn_server {
  server unix:/home/prats/public_html/myapp/current/tmp/sockets/unicorn.sock
  fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
    ...
    ...
    ...
  location / {
    ...
    ...    
    # If you don't find the filename in the static files
    # Then request it from the unicorn server
    if (!-f $request_filename) {
      proxy_pass http://unicorn_server;
      break;
    }
    ...
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Does anyone have any answer to that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ProxyRequests Off

ProxyPass /stylesheets/ !

ProxyPass /javascripts/ !

ProxyPass /images/ !

ProxyPass / http://example.com:8080/

ProxyPassReverse / http://example.com:8080/

Comment: Thanks Mark, so Apache cannot forward the requests to a socket right?

Answer (score 3):

After having searched for quite a while, I came to the conclusion that using Apache2 + Unicorn via sockets is not possible.
The farthest I got was using mod_fastcgi on the socket file that unicorn provides, but I got 403 Forbidden when trying to access the page.
It seems that FastCGI requires a different protocol than the one Unicorn uses.
Stick with the solution from Mark Kolesar if you have to use Unicorn with Apache. Be aware that you might run into problems (taken from http://rubyforge.org/pipermail/mongrel-unicorn/2011-July/001057.html):

> Apache + Unicorn is still unsupported since (as far as anybody knows),
>   it doesn't fully buffer responses and requests to completely isolate
>   Unicorn from the harmful effects of slow clients.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you do it using unixcat in between?
Having the proxypass to localhost:something
xinetd + unixcat installed
/etc/xinetd.d/unicorn holding:

```
service livestatus
{
    type        = UNLISTED
    port        = someport
    socket_type = stream
    protocol    = tcp
    wait        = no
    cps         = 100 3
    instances   = 500
    per_source  = 250
    flags       = NODELAY
    user        = someone
    server      = /usr/bin/unixcat
    server_args = /var/run/unicorn/mysocket
    only_from   = 127.0.0.1
    disable     = no
}
```